# `{% include "blah.html" with x="..." only %}` with default value for x

Tags: django, django-templates

In a template, I am using an `include` like this:

```
{% include "blah.html" with x="..." only %}
```

and I can use `x` in blah.html.

Now, **I would like blah.html to set a default value for `x` if it is not passed by the "parent" template**:

```
{% include "blah.html" only %}
```

Since there is apparently no builtin template tag to set a variable in a template, I don't know how this could be achieved...

Comment: have you tried default_if_none:"" ?

Comment: Yes, that would work, but since I use `x` in many places in blah.html, adding default_if_none at every variable call would make the code heavy.

Comment: A `with` tag nested in an `if` tag can do the trick.